# Editing Venn diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I have used the following code to make a Venn diagram.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}     

        \def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)} \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)} \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
        \draw \firstcircle 
        node[below] {$instinct$};
        \draw \secondcircle
        node [above] {$valar$}; 
        \draw \thirdcircle 
        node [below] {$Mystic$};
     node[center] {} 
        \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[yellow]
        \secondcircle; 
        \end{scope} 
        \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[purple] \thirdcircle; 
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope} 
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle; 
        \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

and get such a result

[image]

I want the center to be white like this 
how do I do that

[image]

Comment: Please don't use math mode (`$  ... $`) for italic text, it is semantically wrong, and it can in some cases give really ugly output do to bad kerning between characters. Use `\textit{Valor}` instead.  (I assume that was a typo, that you didn't mean [valar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(Middle-earth)).)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, adding one `scope` environment for the intersection of the three circles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}     
        \def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)} \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)} \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
        \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[yellow]
        \secondcircle; 
        \end{scope} 
        \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[purple] \thirdcircle; 
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope} 
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle; 
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope} 
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[white] \thirdcircle; 
        \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle 
        node[above] {$Instinct$};
        \draw \secondcircle
        node [above left] {$Valar$}; 
        \draw \thirdcircle 
        node [below right] {$Mystic$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]